# How to get the same subnet in a Windows 7 virtual machine as Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, ip, parallels

I have another Windows 7 laptop and I want to try IGMP protocols using multicasting. I figure it's not working because my OS X has IP `192.168.178.23` and the Windows 7 laptop `192.168.178.100`, but the virtual Windows on OS X has `10.xx.xx.xx`.

So, which type of network should I use?

- Shared
- Bridge

  - Default adapter
  - Ethernet
  - AirPort
  - VNIC0
  - VNIC1
  - host-only

I'm using Windows 7 in Parallels on OS X 10.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was using AirPort in OS X for establishing my local network connection, so I selected *Bridge » AirPort*.